# phonegap production android app to starling. key certificate is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I want to update android html5 app with new as3 app. the problem is that when i use the exisiting certificate key to package in flash builder, i get "incorrect password for this certificate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate a new certificate using `keytool`. In mac, you can execute the following command to generate a new certificate:

```
$ keytool -keystore cert.jks -genkeypair -alias cert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \
  -validity 18250 -dname 'CN=cert,OU=org,O=org,L=location,ST=state,C=PH'

$ keytool -keystore cert.jks -exportcert -alias cert \
  | openssl x509 -inform der -text

$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.jks -destkeystore cert.p12 \
  -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Here's the [process on how to sign your application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).